# SVG howto select elements from use tag

Tags: svg

I use SVG and javascript. I want to use the '`use` element' a lot to keep my xml file small.

Problem is that I can't find a way to change the elements that the `use` tag references. See my code for an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" onload="init()" width="1000" height="900">

    <defs>

        <g id="test">
            <circle cx="10" cy="20" r="20" fill="green" />
            <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="100" y2="60" stroke="red" />
        </g>

    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#test" x="10" y="10" />
    <use xlink:href="#test" x="50" y="50" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        <![CDATA[

        function init()
        {
            var allUses = document.querySelectorAll('[*|href="#test"]');
            for (i = 0; i < allUses.length; i++) {
                allUses[i].addEventListener('mouseover', testOver, false);
            }
        }

        function testOver()
        {
            // on mouse over the element I want the circle the mouse goes over to change color to blue and the line to purple
            // how to get a handle to the circle ???
            //this.[get circle?]
        }

        function attribute(element, name, value)
        {
        element.setAttribute(name, value);
        }

        ]]>
    </script>

</svg>
```

How do I get a handle to the element inside the use element (on a per 'use tag' basis)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do what you want. The inherent nature of `defs` and `use` elements dictates that sub-elements within an original `defs` element cannot be manipulated individually in `use` elements derived from it. To do so would require that each `use` element have a separate copy of each sub-element. That would defeat one of the purposes of the `defs`/`use` partnership, i.e. to save memory.

However, while you cannot change the attributes of one specific sub-element in a `use` element, you *can* change the attributes of *all* of the sub-elements in a `use` element at one time. (Whether such coarse control is sufficient depends on your particular needs.) For example, when copying a `defs` element that has multiple shapes within it, you can change the fill colour of *all* the shapes in one particular `use` element by changing the fill colour of the entire `use` element. This is shown in the code snippet below by changing the fill colour of the moused-over `use` element to red. Note, however, that you can only do so when the attribute you are changing has *not* been specified in the original `defs` element. This is shown in the code snippet below by the fact that you can change to red the fill colour of the circles coloured green in the `use` elements, but not those coloured green in the `defs` element.

One way to accomplish what I think you want to do is to use cloning. When you mouse over a particular `use` element, you can clone whatever you want out of the `defs` element, place it over top of the appropriate shape in the `use` element, and then change that cloned/re-inserted element however you want. This is shown in the code snippet below by cloning the third circle each time you mouse over a `use` element and placing it back into the DOM guided by the coordinates of the `use` element. I made this a little easier to see by slightly offsetting the cloned element. I've also made it disappear when the next mouse-over event happens, but whether you want that behaviour depends on your situation. (Note that placing the cloned element in the correct position can be tricky in a complex document, particularly when there are groups-within-groups and transforms have been applied, e.g. scaling, rotations, translations. In those cases, you probably will need to use `getCTM`/`getScreenCTM`.)

```js
function init() {
  var allUses = document.querySelectorAll('[*|href="#test"]');
  for (i = 0; i < allUses.length; i++) {
    allUses[i].addEventListener('mouseover', testOver, false);
  }
}

function testOver() {
  attribute(this, "fill", "red");
  var circle3 = document.querySelector("defs").querySelector(".circle3").cloneNode(true);
  var highlighted = document.querySelector("#highlighted");
  highlighted.replaceChild(circle3, highlighted.childNodes[0]);
  attribute(circle3, "fill", "blue");
  var x = parseFloat(this.getAttribute("x")) + 4;
  var y = parseFloat(this.getAttribute("y")) + 4;
  attribute(circle3, "transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
}

function attribute(element, name, value) {
  element.setAttribute(name, value);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" onload="init()" width="450" height="150">

  <defs>
    <g id="test">
      <circle class="circle1" cx="10"  cy="20" r="20" fill="green" />
      <circle class="circle2" cx="50"  cy="20" r="20" />
      <circle class="circle3" cx="90"  cy="20" r="20" />
      <circle class="circle4" cx="130" cy="20" r="20" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use class="five" xlink:href="#test" x="10" y="10" fill="green" />
  <use class="five" xlink:href="#test" x="50" y="80" fill="green" />

  <g id="highlighted">
    <g id="dummyElementToBeReplaced">
    </g>
  </g>

</svg>
```